# VBA Renaming OnAction macro assigned to shapes in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba, rename

Trying to rename OnAction macro assigned to shapes and buttons in a different workbook named `objWorkbookToObsfucate`.

The macro name
`"Sample Spreadsheet_original_Temp.xlsm'!showMyTimer"` needs to change to `"Sample Spreadsheet_original_Temp.xlsm'!aW7S2Q41LN5TU4A5SWDO2"`.

I get an 1004 error on the line that sets the macro name `shp.OnAction`.
The macro "aW7S2Q41LN5TU4A5SWDO2" is the new macro name that is renamed on runtime.

For debugging `DoesMacroExist` proves that the new macro name exists in that workbook,`IsWorkbookOpen` proves that the Workbook is Open.
This code sould work for shapes and form buttons on the worksheet.
experiencing a strange behavior, Sometimes it works and sometimes it fails.

```vb
    Public Sub OnActionMacroRename(ByRef objWorkbookToObsfucate As Workbook, ByVal OriginalOnActionMacroName As String, ByVal ModifiedOnActionMacroName As String, ByVal shapecopy As String)
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim shp As Shape
        Dim OriginalMacroName As String
        Dim ModifiedMacroName As String
        Dim i As Long
        
        Debug.Print "Attempting to set OnAction to: " & ModifiedOnActionMacroName
        Debug.Print "Looking for shape with name: " & shapecopy
        
    ' Loop through all sheets in objWorkbookToObsfucate
        For Each ws In objWorkbookToObsfucate.Sheets
            ' Skip if no shapes
             If ws.Shapes.count = 0 Then GoTo NextSheet
                 ' Loop through all shapes in ws of objWorkbookToObsfucate
                 For Each shp In ws.Shapes
                        Debug.Print "Shape name: " & shp.Name
                         ' Find original SHP
                             If shp.Name = shapecopy Then
                                    Debug.Print shapecopy & " shape Found . Attempting to set OnAction for AutoShape."
                                    Debug.Print "ModifiedOnActionMacroName: " & ModifiedOnActionMacroName
                                    Debug.Print ws.CodeName
                                    Debug.Print shp.Parent.Parent.Name
                                                                     
                                     ' Checks before setting the OnAction property
                                    If IsWorkbookOpen("Sample Spreadsheet_original_Temp.xlsm") Then
                                            Dim wb As Workbook
                                            Set wb = Workbooks("Sample Spreadsheet_original_Temp.xlsm")
                                                If DoesMacroExist(wb, "aW7S2Q41LN5TU4A5SWDO2") Then
                                                ''Bug is here!!
                                                    ''Rename shape in Workbook objWorkbookToObsfucate
                                                    ''shp.OnAction = ModifiedOnActionMacroName
                                                    shp.OnAction = "'Sample Spreadsheet_original_Temp.xlsm'!aW7S2Q41LN5TU4A5SWDO2"
                                                Else
                                                    MsgBox "Macro not found."
                                                End If
                                     Else
                                            MsgBox "Workbook not open."
                                     End If
                                   Exit For
                             End If
                Next
    NextSheet:
        Next ws
    Exit Sub
    End Sub
    
    ' Function to check if workbook is open
    Function IsWorkbookOpen(wbName As String) As Boolean
        Dim wb As Workbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks(wbName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        IsWorkbookOpen = Not wb Is Nothing
    End Function
    
    ' Function to check if a macro exists in a workbook
    Function DoesMacroExist(wb As Workbook, macroName As String) As Boolean
        Dim vbComp As Object
        Dim vbMod As Object
        Dim lineNum As Long
        Dim lineText As String
        
        For Each vbComp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
            If vbComp.Type = 1 Then ' 1 is vbext_ct_StdModule
                Set vbMod = vbComp.codeModule
                With vbMod
                    For lineNum = 1 To .CountOfLines
                        lineText = .Lines(lineNum, 1)
                        If InStr(1, lineText, "Sub " & macroName & "(", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            DoesMacroExist = True
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    Next lineNum
                End With
            End If
        Next vbComp
        DoesMacroExist = False
    End Function
```

Comment: Could the Worksheet that the Shape / Button is on be protected?

Comment: The Worksheet is not protected

Comment: After addin the line objWorkbookToObsfucate.Activate it seams to work, looks like somting like a userform was interapting changing focus to the other workbook.

Comment: Activating objWorkbookToObsfucate solves the probem, but I can do it only manually. objWorkbookToObsfucate.Activate does nothing. Also Windows API like FindWindow SetForegroundWindow does not help setting the focus.

Comment: This solve the isuue:                                                    
objWorkbookToObsfucate.Activate
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized                                                                           Question colsed.